# How to check if a service is running in chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

In a recipe file, i need to check if a service is already running. If it is, I need to stop it.

I have

```
service "apache" do
    supports :status => true
    action :stop
end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to check that? `service "apache" do action :start end` should be enough - as chef will check itself, if the service running. If it is, it will do nothing.

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/q/534498/144062) might be close.  Draco has the right idea though, tell it to start.  If it doesn't, you will get feedback very soon in your next commands that rely on that service.  But you can use chef to run system commands, so you could do a service check as you would on the system and evaluate the signal or the output.

Comment: @DracoAter Check my edited question. I didn't frame the question properly. I need to stop a service if its enabled.

Comment: Same thing. Your code should work. Just tells it to stop, it will stop if it's running and do nothing if it's already stopped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chef is declarative. So the code you've written does exactly what you've described.

Comment: Is it possible to do a switch case for starting and stopping the service? I'm having a hard time with this.

Ideally, I want to stop the service if its running and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, you can switch on the `:action`, but why? I don't understand your use case.

Comment: It's a bit complicated. Everytime we run chef-client on the chef provisioned instance, our recipe needs to stop & start at different times to let other recipes do their stuff since we have a lot of dependency. So, I'm actually trying to understanding this 'switch' statment from the documentation, i'm not able to make out anything.

Comment: I don't think you should approach the problem this way then. If you have these kinds of dependencies, you should use notifications instead: http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#notifications. You can subscribe and notify events to happen before/after things.

Comment: Thanks @sethvargo. But for knowledge sake, if i wanted to do a switch on `:action`, how would i do it? 

It's good to know for small time stuff.

Comment: Shouldn't i do it on the `:status`? Check if status is true of false and then execute the action?

Comment: You can, but then you're going to have to shell out and probably have some really nasty code.

Answer (score 2):

```
service "apache" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :start => true
  action [ :start ]
end
```

If the service is already running, it wont do any thing. but if stopped, it will start the service